# Skip function when Toplevel is active

Tags: python, function, tkinter, toplevel

I'm trying to skip this function if the Toplevel window is currently open. This is to avoid a user spamming the button and creating a billion extra notification windows. That or if the Toplevel window could close automatically after a specified amount of time would also work. Code is below. Any assistance is greatly appreciated as I am pretty new to Python. Thanks!

```
def pingClick():
    os.system(
        '-c -H ' + tkvar1.get() + ' -B ' + tkvar2.get() + ' -L ' + tkvar3.get() + ' -V ' + tkvar4.get() + ' -T log.log')
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Ping")
    msg = Message(top, text=" - Notice - ")
    msg.pack()
    button = ttk.Button(top, text="Dismiss", command=top.destroy)
    button.pack()
```

Comment: create global variable `top = None` and assing `Toplevel()` to this global variable and then you can check if it is `None` or not and create window or not. When you destroy window then assign again `None`

Comment: you can use `top.after(milliseconds, function_name)` to run function which will destroy window afer `milliseconds`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create global variable `top = None`. When you create `Toplevel()` then first check if `top` is `None`. When it is not `None` then dont't create window. When you click button to destroy window then you have to run function which set it back `top = None`. You have to do also when you close window using button `[X]`

And you can use `top.after(3000, ping_destroy)` to close window after 3000ms (3s)

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def ping_destroy():
    global top

    if top is not None:
        top.destroy()
        top = None

def ping_click():
    global top

    if top is None:
        #os.system('-c -H ' + tkvar1.get() + ' -B ' + tkvar2.get() + ' -L ' + tkvar3.get() + ' -V ' + tkvar4.get() + ' -T log.log')
        top = tk.Toplevel()
        top.title("Ping")

        msg = tk.Message(top, text="Notice")
        msg.pack()

        button = tk.Button(top, text="Dismiss", command=ping_destroy)
        button.pack()

        top.wm_protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', ping_destroy) # run `ping_destroy` when use button [X]

        top.after(3000, ping_destroy) # close after 3000ms (3s)

# --- main ---

top = None

root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root, text='Ping', command=ping_click)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try!